# A word for one thing that is masquerading as two (The "Double Issue" issue)

Tags: meaning, synonyms

I am trying to figure out the best way to describe this seemingly specific name, the "Double Issue". In English, Double has many meanings, but the main uses all basically mean 2 of something, in some way shape or form. In the situation I am about to describe, the word Double does not mean what most English speakers intuitively think it does. (Note I am not trying to dispute its defined meaning or anything)

If I were to call an issue release of some kind of content a Double Issue, most people will intuitively think it has twice the content, because that is what double means in most circumstances. However, for [Weekly Shonen Jump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weekly_Sh%C5%8Dnen_Jump) (basically a collection of chapters of Japanese Comics released almost every week, usually of the Genre called [Shonen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sh%C5%8Dnen)), as well as many other Magazines it seems, It has a whole other meaning. In these cases, it is a single issue, with no more content than normal, that is labeled as 2 different issues. So, one week they will release issue 3, then the next, it is issue 4-5. they then do not release another issue the next week, and resume with issue 6 the week after that. Issue 4-5 is called a Double Issue by most English people, but to anyone who does not explicitly know what that means, they of course think there will be twice the content. Shonen Jump specifically releases only 48 issues. Over the course of 52 weeks, they release 48 Issues, with 48 issues worth of content, but 4 of them are counted as double, and so are labeled as such, so number 48 is labeled issue 52.

What I am looking for, is a better word to describe this issue than Double. Does anyone know a better word or phrase than double to describe this kind of thing?

Edit: As noted above, some people brought up that Double issue by default means exactly what was described. While I did not know that, It does not change my original intent, looking for a substitute word or short phrase that could also be used to describe this to others without the built in deception of Double. Another note, words that imply "once every two weeks" like Biweekly, do not fit this description. Shonen jump specifically is a Weekly Magazine, so using words like Biweekly to describe any of its Issues does not fit at all. The word/Phrase could likely also be a substitute for Leap in Leap Year. Though, If we can't find a good intuitive word/phrase, Leap might actually work.

Comment: How about *swindle issue* (see http://www.dictionary.com/browse/swindle)

Comment: "A biweekly issue"... actually don't do that; "biweekly" is also confusing. "a two-week issue" seems fine

Comment: The usage is completely "normal", in that this sort of magazine issue has been referred to as a "double issue" since 1960, at least.  In fact, [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZjtVAAAAYAAJ&q=%22double+issue%22&dq=%22double+issue%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiB5a36yPzQAhUp3IMKHWlUCwwQ6AEIODAG) is a usage in 1956.  You can hunt for a more "honest" term, but "double issue" is completely idiomatic, in this sense.

Comment: Think about it:  "Double vision" doesn't mean you get twice as much vision.  In fact, your vision is less effective than it would be with a single eye open.

Comment: @HotLicks It may be normal, but its not intuitive. Every time it happens I see comments asking what is up by people. Also, besides the fact that double vision is already explicitly defined for most people, If you simplified it, its likely to become something like seeing twice, which implies seeing the same thing two times, yet also at the same time. Double Issue Simplified in any way still says Twice the content without some additional Information.

Comment: "Double issue" is likewise already defined -- has been for 50-odd years.  I've seen the term used easily 50 times.  Is it dishonest to use the term for an issue that does not contain two of anything, other than the publication dates?  Yes.  But since when has honesty been high on the list of aspirations for US businesses?

Comment: For the last several years, TV Guide mostly issues one magazine every 2 weeks, except during periods with lots of TV news, like the start of a season. They still call these "Special Double Issue", even though they're the norm now.

Comment: If I had to go by the title of your question: **hendiadys**. :)

Comment: Perhaps a *skip issue*?

Comment: "Joint issue" comes to mind.

Answer (score 1):

"combined" issue.  Instead of publishing, for example, March and April separately, you are combining the two months.

Answer (score -1):

**Duplicity** most accurate.

I like making up words so I made a list for you. * is a real word/phrase.

- Fortnighter
- Half Lunar*
- Two Weeks One Cut
- Twoishu
- Semi Duece
- Doublette
- Twofacedness*
- Twocrisy
- Binal*
- Bipartisan*
- Duelistic*
- Unduelistic
- Doubleheader*
- Splissue

Here are the words relating to occasional calendar alterations, none are what you need but if you flip the words they might do the trick.

> intercalation
>
> embolismic
>
> biseptile

Or make a chimera, **interbiseptismic**

Comment: ...or Semi Deuce?

Comment: A lot of these seem like replacements for "every two weeks", rather than "one masquerading as two", though Im not sure Masquerading is really the right way to say it either.